# Query works in phpmyadmin but doesn't show id's on page

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this query

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, e.*, d.* 
FROM categories a 
JOIN categories b ON(a.categoryID=b.parentCategory) 
JOIN products c ON(b.categoryID=c.categoryID) 
LEFT JOIN productprice d ON (d.productID = c.productID) 
JOIN currency e ON (e.currencyID = 1)   
WHERE a.categoryID in (263,264,265,266,267,268,306,256,0) 
ORDER BY a.priority
```

When I run the query directly in the phpmyadmin I've got correct result and everything is there.

The problem is when I run it on the page and then trying to display `productID` I've got `NULL`. This is what I'm trying on the page

```
$query = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, e.*, d.* 
FROM categories a 
JOIN categories b ON(a.categoryID=b.parentCategory) 
JOIN products c ON(b.categoryID=c.categoryID) 
LEFT JOIN productprice d ON (d.productID = c.productID) 
JOIN currency e ON (e.currencyID = 1)   
WHERE a.categoryID in (263,264,265,266,267,268,306,256,0) 
ORDER BY a.priority";

$result= mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result) {

      var_dump($row->productID);
}
```

All $row->productID are `NULL`.

Update: `var_dump($result);` return

```
resource(286) of type (mysql result)
```

Comment: First of all mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead and put a var_dump() or ptint_r() on $result and check the data

Comment: @MayankPandeyz I know it's deprecated. I don't use it on production. I've updated my question

Comment: "
Warning

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:

    mysqli_affected_rows()
    PDOStatement::rowCount()

"

Comment: @Dagon, as I said this is my test environment. I don't use it on production! Please read my comment above.

Comment: That really does not matter

Comment: Okay. It's pointless to continue this conversation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Please try with this query

$query = "SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*, e.*, d.* ,c.productID as productID
FROM categories a 
JOIN categories b ON(a.categoryID=b.parentCategory) 
JOIN products c ON(b.categoryID=c.categoryID) 
LEFT JOIN productprice d ON (d.productID = c.productID) 
JOIN currency e ON (e.currencyID = 1)   
WHERE a.categoryID in (263,264,265,266,267,268,306,256,0) 
ORDER BY a.priority"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working like this. So it is not enough to select them like `c.*`..

Comment: It's always better to SELECT the columns you really need.

Comment: Noted. But in this case why they are shown on phpmyadmin i.e. they are selected but aren't on page?

Comment: Is there too may columns to retrieve?

Comment: Yes, they are a lot.. 10+